# Как задать масштаб странице

Tags: html, jquery, css

Есть страница, как сделать так, если разрешение экрана меньше или равно `1024`, то размер страницы становился такой, как будто мы нажали `ctrl-`(с масштабом 80%)

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {       
   if( 
         $(window).width()<= 1024
   ){
       /*IF IE9*/
       if (!('querySelector' in document)  //скорее всего ie 9+
          || !('localStorage' in window)  //ie 8+
          || !('addEventListener' in window)  //ie 8 + (возможно)
          || !('matchMedia' in window)) {//ie 10+
          //действия которые должны сработать для IE.

          $("body").css({"zoom":"80%", "padding-left":"20px"}); 
          $(".left_sidebar").css("left","-4px");
       }
       else {
           $("body").css("zoom","80%");    
           $("body").css("-ms-zoom","80%");
       }   
    }
}).resize();
```

Comment: [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#Browser_Compatibility) поддерживается в IE, начиная с восьмой версии.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7190742/4928642

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Следующий код масштабирует страницу до 1024px = 100% при условии, что доступная ширина меньше 1024. Если больше, то страница показывается в единичном масштабе.

https://jsfiddle.net/xgqw5bjo/3/

Обращаю внимание, что [вариант с использованием jQuery для задания стилей](https://jsfiddle.net/xgqw5bjo/2/) не работает, поскольку он сам обрабатывает префиксы, а тут их нужно контролировать вручную.

```js
~function () {
  var $window = $(window), $body = $("body");
  var ie = document.documentMode;
  
  function updateSizes() {
    var width = $window.width(), scale = Math.min(width / 1024, 1);

    var style = $body[0].style;
    
    style.msZoom = ie === 8 || ie === 9 ? scale : 1;
    style.zoom = ie === 10 || ie === 11 ? 1 : scale;
    style.mozTransform = "scale(" + scale + ")";
    style.oTransform = "scale(" + scale + ")";
    style.transform = "scale(" + scale + ")";
  }

  $window.resize(updateSizes);
  updateSizes();
}();
```

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  transform-origin: top left;
}

@supports (transform: scale(1)) {
  body {
    -ms-zoom: 1 !important;
    zoom: 1 !important;
  }
}

div {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 128px;
  background: url(//i.stack.imgur.com/eMSCb.png) repeat-x;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, blue, red 256px);
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Теоретически (не проверял) должно работать так:

- IE 5.5 - 7 <kbd>zoom</kbd>
- IE 8 - 9 <kbd>-ms-zoom</kbd>
- IE 10 - 11 <kbd>transform</kbd> & <kbd>ie</kbd>
- Edge 12+ <kbd>transform</kbd> & <kbd>@supports</kbd>
- Opera 11.5 - 12.0 <kbd>-o-transform</kbd>
- Opera 12.1 <kbd>transform</kbd>
- Firefox 3.5 - 15 <kbd>-moz-transform</kbd>
- Firefox 16+ <kbd>transform</kbd>
- Firefox 22+ <kbd>transform</kbd> (есть `@supports`, но `zoom` всё равно нет)
- Safari 4 - 8 <kbd>zoom</kbd>
- Safari 9+ <kbd>transform</kbd> & <kbd>@supports</kbd> (появились одновременно - повезло)
- Chrome 4 - 27 <kbd>zoom</kbd>
- Chrome 28 - 35 <kbd>zoom</kbd> (есть `@supports`, но ещё нет `transform`)
- Chrome 36+ <kbd>transform</kbd> & <kbd>@supports</kbd>

Если добавить `-webkit-transform`, то появится поддержка Safari 3.1 - 3.2, но многое сломается, так что лучше не надо.

Т. о. для современных браузеров результат тем или иным способом сводится к использованию `transform` и уничтожению `zoom`. Во всех совсем современных и развивающися (Edge, Firefox, Safari, Chrome) в итоге уже получилось <kbd>transform</kbd> & <kbd>@supports</kbd>, что соответствует стандарту, а следовательно, скорее всего не сломается в будущем.

Проверено в (пожалуйста, дополняйте список, если проверяете в другом браузере):

- IE 11
- Edge 15
- Opera 12.18
- Firefox 50
- Safari 5 (Win)
- Safari 10 (Mac)
- Chrome 54

Детали по поддержке браузерами:

- http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-zoom
- http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-featurequeries (это про `@supports`)
- http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

PS: А вообще, правильнее было сделать нормальный responsive-дизайн.

Comment: расскажите как работает ваш код, а то что-то не понятно))

Comment: @ChromeChrome, сейчас, допишу костыль на IE10-11. А вообще, я вроде добавил описание уже?

Comment: честно говоря я не понимаю, как ваш код мне поможет ведь мне нужно было сделать такую проверку, если ширина экрана меньше 1024 пикселей, то странице делать масштаб в 80%, а ваш код этого не делает

Comment: @ChromeChrome, _"масштаб в 80%"_ - замени в присваивание `scale` на такое: `scale = width < 1024 ? .8 : 1`. Просто я сделал масштабирование с подгонкой к ширине в ответе.

Comment: всё равно полной схожести не будет, если нажить ctrl-, а на в другой вкладке запустить скрипт, то всё равно разница будет колоссальной)

Comment: @ChromeChrome, а можно пример на jsfiddle?

Comment: @ChromeChrome, я так понимаю, получилось?

Comment: не совсем, то что я хотел, но всё равно спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 0):

Можно обойтись без JavaScript одним CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024) {
  body { zoom: 80%; }
}
```

Проверял только в Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

Ваш код работает когда пользователь сам изменяет масштаб, да и в коде ошибка при указании значения для `zoom`, он не в процентах, попробуйте так

```
$(function () {       
    if($(window).width()<= 1024) {
       /*IF IE9*/
       if (!('querySelector' in document)  //скорее всего ie 9+
          || !('localStorage' in window)  //ie 8+
          || !('addEventListener' in window)  //ie 8 + (возможно)
          || !('matchMedia' in window)) {//ie 10+
          //действия которые должны сработать для IE.

          $("body").css({"zoom":"80", "padding-left":"20px"}); 
          $(".left_sidebar").css("left","-4px");
       }
       else {
           $("body").css("zoom","80");    
           $("body").css("-ms-zoom","80");
       }   
    }
});
```

**Пример:**

```js
$(function () {     
  if($(window).width()<= prompt("Ширина экрана:", "1024")) {
    /*IF IE9*/
    if (!('querySelector' in document)  //скорее всего ie 9+
        || !('localStorage' in window)  //ie 8+
        || !('addEventListener' in window)  //ie 8 + (возможно)
        || !('matchMedia' in window)) {//ie 10+
      //действия которые должны сработать для IE.

      $("body").css({"zoom":"80", "padding-left":"20px"}); 
      $(".left_sidebar").css("left","-4px");
    }
    else {
      $("body").css("zoom","80");    
      $("body").css("-ms-zoom","80");
    }   
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Header</h2>
<p>Some text...</p>
```

Comment: 1. `zoom` не `80`, а `.8`. 2. Проверки на IE странные. 3. А как насчёт Firefox, в котором нет и никогда не было `zoom`?

Comment: @Qwertiy код взят из вопроса

Comment: Но если бы код в вопросе работал, то и задавать его не было бы смысла :)

Comment: Кстати, в вопросе был zoom в процентах - это бы работало. А вот без процентов - это увеличение в 80 раз.