# Как узнать о поддержке браузером CSS свойства?

Tags: javascript, css

Хочу написал кроссбраузерный сайт, который будет работать корректно во многих браузерах.

Существует ли какой нибудь метод для определения, поддерживает браузер это CSS свойство или нет? Можно ли это как-то узнать с помощью одного CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для проверки в css есть директива `@supports`, которая похожа на `@media`, но в качестве запросов получает пары `(свойство: значение)`. Для проверки из скриптов есть функция `CSS.supports`, которой можно передать аргументами свойство и значение, либо единственным аргументом полностью сформированный запрос.

Разумеется, у этого всего тоже есть поддержка браузерами и она гораздо меньше, чем у некоторых свойств.

```js
if (window.CSS && CSS.supports) {
  console.log(CSS.supports('-webkit-appearance', 'none'));
  console.log(CSS.supports('-webkit-appearance: none'));
  console.log(CSS.supports('appearance', 'none'));
  console.log(CSS.supports('appearance: none'));
  console.log(CSS.supports('(-webkit-appearance: none) or (appearance: none)'));
}
```

```css
@supports (display: contents) {
  body {
    background: silver;
  }
}

@supports (pointer-events: none) {
  body {
    color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
Just some text
```

Скриншоты из Firefox 58 и Chrome 63:
[image: скриншот FF 58]
[image: скриншот Chrome 63]

Ссылки:

- https://habrahabr.ru/post/178021/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/@supports
- https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CSS/supports
- https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-featurequeries
- Более интересный пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594479/178988

Comment: Мне кажется, или на каком-то таком же вопросе был мой ответ :D

Comment: Не знаю, я сам написал этот ответ :)

Comment: А, нашёл: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/710801/178988

Comment: Помёрджить вопросы?