# Как узнать о поддержке браузером CSS свойства?

Tags: javascript, css

Хочу сделать сайт, который будет корректно выглядеть в большинстве браузеров. Но на пути к созданию столкнулся с проблемой кроссбраузерности. То есть, один браузер поддерживает данное CSS, а другой — нет.

Как я могу знать, поддерживает ли данный браузер указанное CSS свойство? Можно ли это узнать на одном CSS?

Comment: Просто пилим сайт под IE8 (с полифиллами) и периодически поглядываем чтобы в каком-нибудь современном браузере не разъезжалось — IE8 не поддерживает новые CSS, кроссбраузерность гарантирована :D

Comment: @andreymal, идея интересная, но не все старые браузера запустятся на новых ОС :) Хотя, как ответ можете предложить.

Comment: modernizr - это всё что нужно

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### С помощью одного CSS

Узнать, поддерживает ли данный браузер указанное CSS свойство, можно через CSS директиву под названием *[@supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/@supports)*.

Эта директива работает так же, как и @media.

```
/* Узнаём, поддерживает ли браузер display: flex; */
@supports (display: flex) {
   /* Стили */
}
```

Так же можно установить свойства при условии, если браузер не поддерживает указанное CSS свойство

```
/* Узнаём, поддерживает ли браузер display: flex; */
@supports not (display: flex) {
   /* Стили */
}
```

Ещё можно проверить несколько свойств сразу, используя оператор `and`

```
/* Узнаём, поддерживает ли браузер display: flex; и flex-wrap: wrap; */
@supports (display: flex) and (flex-wrap: wrap) {
   /* Стили */
}
```

А если нам нужно хотя бы одно рабочее свойство, можно использовать оператор `or`

```
/* Узнаём, поддерживает ли браузер display: flex; */
@supports (display: flex) or (display: -webkit-flex) {
   /* Стили */
}
```

Но нужно учесть, что данная директива новая и в IE вообще не работает.

Так же, для обеспечения, какой никакой, кроссбраузерности, можете использовать [вендорные префиксы](http://yapro.ru/web-master/css/vendornie-prefiksi.html).

---

### С помощью JS

Данную задачу, с помощью JS, я знаю, как решить двумя способами:

1. ***Использовать аналог CSS @Supports только на JS — функцию [`CSS.supports()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CSS/supports)***

   ```
   // Узнаём, поддерживает ли браузер display: flex;
   CSS.supports("display", "flex"); // true/false
   ```

   Так же, как и в CSS, можно указать несколько свойств.

   ```
   // Узнаём, поддерживает ли браузер display: flex; и flex-wrap: wrap;
   CSS.supports("( display: flex ) and ( flex-wrap: wrap )"); // true/false
   ```

   Но так же, как и в CSS, этот метод является новым и не будет работать в IE вообще.
2. ***Проверить с помощью применения стилей через JS.***

   Суть этого метода в том, что браузер не может установить свойству элемента значение, которое не поддерживает. Таким образом, если, после применения нового значения свойству через JavaScript, оно не изменилось, то браузер не поддерживает данное значение.

   В итоге у нас выходит следующая функция:

   ```
   var SupportsCSS = function (property, value) {
      try {
         // Создаём новый элемент
         var element = document.createElement('span');
         // Проверяем, есть ли такое свойство в браузере
         if (element.style[property] !== undefined) 
            element.style[property] = value; // Если есть, то присваиваем
         else 
            return false; // Если нет, то false

         // Если браузер поддерживает данное значение для указанного свойства, то значения будут равны
         return element.style[property] === value;
      } catch (e) {
         // В случае со старым IE, при присваивании значения, которое не поддерживается, вылетает ошибка
         return false;
      }
   };
   ```

   И вот так это работает:

   ```js
   var SupportsCSS = function (property, value) {
       try {
           var element = document.createElement('span');
           if (element.style[property] !== undefined) 
               element.style[property] = value;
           else 
               return false;

           return element.style[property] === value;
       } catch (e) {
           return false;
       }
   };

   // Проверяем
   console.log( SupportsCSS('display', 'flex') );
   console.log( SupportsCSS('display', '-webkit-box') );
   console.log( SupportsCSS('display', 'Lol :)') );
   console.log( SupportsCSS('flex-wrap', 'wrap') );
   console.log( SupportsCSS('-webkit-flex-wrap', 'nowrap') );
   ```

   > *Примечание:* Если вы проверяете поддержку свойства в старом браузере, через эмулятор современного браузера, то данный метод будем показывать *true* на значениях, которые не поддерживаются.

   Преимущество этого метода в том, что он будет работать во всех браузерах.

   Пример запуска скрипта в Safari 5.17:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Специальные сервисы

Чтобы не заморачиваться, поддержу можно посмотреть на специальных сайтах. К примеру, один из самых популярных сайтов — http://caniuse.com/

---

<sup>Подробнее можно прочитать здесь: https://habrahabr.ru/post/336466/</sup>

Comment: Если уж речь зашла не только про css, но и про js, то думаю есть смысл ещё упомянуть про [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/)

Comment: @MedvedevDev, можете добавить это собственным ответом. Я не смогу нормально рассказать про эту библиотеку, так как никогда с ней не работал.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, я вообще для людей писал... :) Отредактировал

Answer (score 6):

### Modernizr

> [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) — это JavaScript-библиотека, которая узнаёт, что из HTML5 и CSS3 умеет браузер пользователя.

Если вкратце, то библиотека добавляет классы вашему `<html>` опираясь на которые можно выбирать какие свойства будет использовать элемент:

```
.block { display: flex; }
html:not(.flexbox) .block { display: block; }
```

Методы для js:

```
if(Modernizr.touchevents) {
  // do something ...
}
```

Так же тестирование тех или иных возможностей браузера, скажем для выбора "подключать полифилы или нет":

```
Modernizr.load({
  test: Modernizr.geolocation,
  yep : 'geo.js',
  nope: 'geo-polyfill.js'
});
```

Более подробно можно почитать в статье на Хабре - [Modernizr: практическое применение](https://habrahabr.ru/post/144352/)