# Запретить масштабирование windows для вебсайта

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть горизонтальный сайт, и если у пользователя выбрано масштабирование в windows то он едет вниз, можно ли запретить масштабировать сайт несмотря на установки windows? Прикрепляю скрин как это выглядит при масштабе 125% в windows. нужно чтобы всегда было как будто у пользователя 100%[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: О, как-то год назад всё перерыл, но так и не осилил этот вопрос. Всё решил банальной адаптацией (media).

Comment: В медиа запросах можно задать, что у ползователя стоит масштабирование?

Comment: Нет... (а может да? но я не нашел). Я просто по итогу выяснил что при включеном масштабе меняется разрешение ну типа не 1920 а точно не помню но кароче меньше (выяснил путем добавления кода js). Вот в итоге под эти "странные разрешения" и сделал адаптацию. Вот кстати мож [этот](https://www.mydevice.io/) сервис поможет

Comment: Нет способа запретить масштабирование (так как и нет способа его определить).. Нужно верстать адаптивные сайты

Comment: А воспроизводимый пример можно?

Comment: @InDevX Вы не правы, смотрите мой ответ

Comment: @StrangerintheQ довольно интересный ответ, не знал что так можно (ну и не искал особо ничего об этом). Но так делать нельзя. Это противоречит принципу доступности информации; фактически то же, что и запретить всем желающим читать книги или смотреть видео

Comment: @InDevX это нужно например чтобы на ретине ваши кнопочки не стали маленькие премаленькие :), особенно актуально когда все на канве отрендерено

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Есть такое свойство [`window.devicePixelRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio). При помощи него можно определить ретину или измененный масштаб браузера.

Пробуйте менять масштаб `ctrl+scroll`

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', e => {
  preventZoom.style.zoom = 1/devicePixelRatio;
  preventZoom.style['-moz-transform'] = `scale(${1/devicePixelRatio})` ;
})
```

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">deafult</div>
<div class="block" id="preventZoom">prevent zoom</div>
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/nbcUROK.png Что я делаю не так?

Comment: @Александр это какой браузер ?

Comment: Firefox последний. На хроме отлично работает даже с windows scaling.

Comment: @Александр добавил св-во для мозиллы, но с ним все не так, смотрите

Comment: спасибо, а нельзя определять с какого устройств зашел пользователь и только тогда запрещать скейлинг или это уже на другом языке только?

Comment: @Александр можно по userAgent пробовать, но никаких гарантий, плюс масштабмрование в системе и всякие 4k мониторы все равно так не определить

Comment: Единственный минус, что скрипт выполняется только после того когда пользователь хоть один раз сделает ctrl + scroll, при f5 все равно уезжает.

Comment: @Александр ну это решается одним вызовом сразу после загрузки страницы

Comment: Такая проблема в фаерфоксе только, в хроме все хорошо, только не понятно почему работает только с id, а с классами не работает.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96646/discussion-between-stranger-in-the-q-and-).

Comment: 1. А почему не css? 2. Кроссбраузерное масштабирование я уже делал: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594479/178988 // cc @Александр